# Как Вы предотвращаете SQL Injection?

Tags: php, безопасность, sql

Как Вы обычно предотвращаете SQL Injection в своём PHP коде?

Например,

```
$unsafeVal = $_POST['val'];
ExecSQL("insert into T (val) values ('" . $unsafe . "')");
```

Имеется в виду - когда не используется большой фреймворк типа Symfony. Или без них уже не пишете? :)

Comment: самый простой способ - проверять значения. Если должно быть число, значит проверить с помощью [ctype_digit](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php). Если емейл, то соответствующей регуляркой. Строки ескейпить. Большое кол-во injection победите.

Comment: mysqli/PDO + bindparam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использование параметризованных запросов

```
// Запрос
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE something = ?";
// Подставляем параметры
sqlsrv_query($connection, $query, array('some data'));
```